# MobileFirst 7.1 integration with WCS7(fep 8) Aurora store

Tags: android, wcs

I am following [Steps](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.aurora-starterstore.doc/concepts/csmmobileappworklight.htm) provided by IBM to build MobileFirst hybrid application for default Aurora store. I found the desired WCWorklight.zip at location

> C:\{Installation dir}\components\store-enhancements\samples\Worklight\

On tutorial there were many js files that need to be replaced but those were not present in **WCWorklight.zip** [e.g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlJZz.png).

After building the apk when I ran it it is throwing error

> `Process: com.ibm.commerce.worklight.android, PID: 3001
>                                                                                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.worklight.location.internal.nativeImpl.AndroidWLDevice
>                                                                                         at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.<init>(WLClient.java:177)
>                                                                                         at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.createInstance(WLClient.java:229)
>                                                                                         at com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Logger.java:549)
>                                                                                         at com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap.onCreate(WLDroidGap.java:43)
>                                                                                         at com.ibm.commerce.worklight.android.WCHybrid.onCreate(WCHybrid.java:143)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Please let me know if any one faced such issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And it sounds like you need to contact IBM WebSphere Commerce is you have missing files; you can't be helped about this in Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Commerce specifically mentions that you need Worklight 6.0, where you are using 7.1.

You need to check if there is a version that is updated for 7.1.
7.1 is wholly different from 6.0 (by years of development).

Contact IBM WebSphere Commerce.